# Unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \rightarrow R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know if $\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow R$, where are $R$ is an arbitrary commutative ring, for any $r \in R$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism extending the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ given by $n \mapsto n \cdot 1$, sending $x$ to $r$. I know it is usually written as $\text{ev}_r$ where $\text{ev}_r(x)=r$. How could you extend this idea to a unique evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \rightarrow R$ extending the unique ring homomorphism, sending $x$ to $r$ and $y$ to $s$ for arbitrary $r,s \in R$? What would the notation be? Would the proper way to write it be $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(xy)=(rs)$? How do I prove the evaluation of two variables is a homomorphism?

Comment: If $R$ is not commutative, then not all pairs $(r,s) \in R \times R$ will work. The pair $(r,s)$ works only if $r$ and $s$ commute with each other, i.e., $rs=sr$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang sorry $R$ is commutative

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang could you right the map as $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(x,y)=(r,s)$?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Or could you write it as $\phi(f(x,y))=f(r,s)$?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang or should I write it as $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(xy)=rs$?

Comment: I don't think the notation is that important, but I'm sure $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}$ is fine. Indeed, $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(xy)=rs$.

Comment: @Dave thanks, I was wondering how you would show it is a homomorphism?

Comment: Since $x,y$ generate $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ as a $\mathbb Z$-algebra, you can define a map $\mathbb Z[x,y]\to R$ by sending $x\mapsto r$ and $y\mapsto s$ and *extending* this to a ring homomorphism. So the fact that it is a ring homomorphism is part of the definition essentially. The only thing to check is that the relations of the domain are preserved through the map, but you get this for free here since $x,y$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: @Dave could you write $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}((f+g)(x,y))=\text_{ev}_{(r,s)}(f(x,y)+g(x,y))=f(r,s)+g(r,s)$? To show it preserves addition? But that wouldn't make sense to me.